# How to create adjacency matrix from grid coordinates in R?

Tags: r, coordinates, coordinate, adjacency-matrix

I'm new to this site. I was wondering if anyone had experience with turning a list of grid coordinates (shown in example code below as df). I've written a function that can handle the job for very small data sets but the run time increases exponentially as the size of the data set increases (I think 800 pixels would take about 25 hours). It's because of the nested for loops but I don't know how to get around it.

```
## Dummy Data
x <- c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3)
y <- c(3,4,2,3,4,1,2)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
df

## Here's what it looks like as an image
a <- c(NA,NA,1,1)
b <- c(NA,1,1,1)
c <- c(1,1,NA,NA)
image <- cbind(a,b,c)
f <- function(m) t(m)[,nrow(m):1]
image(f(image))

## Here's my adjacency matrix function that's slowwwwww
adjacency.coordinates <- function(x,y) {
  df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
  colnames(df) = c("V1","V2")
  df <- df[with(df,order(V1,V2)),]
  adj.mat <- diag(1,dim(df)[1])
  for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]) {
    for (j in 1:dim(df)[1]) {
      if((df[i,1]-df[j,1]==0)&(abs(df[i,2]-df[j,2])==1) | (df[i,2]-df[j,2]==0)&(abs(df[i,1]-df[j,1])==1)) {
        adj.mat[i,j] = 1
      }
    }
  }
  return(adj.mat)
}

## Here's the adjacency matrix
adjacency.coordinates(x,y)
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this that will work well on a set of coordinates a couple thousand pixels long? I've tried conversion to SpatialGridDataFrame and went from there but it won't get the adjacency matrix correct. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: The OP apparently wants the adjacency matrix of
the graph whose vertices are the "on" pixels of the image
(`x` and `y` are the pixel coordinates; there are 7 pixels in the example),
with an edge between two pixels if they are neighbours.
It is a subgraph of the 2-dimensional grid.
(The image can be replicated as: 
`im <- matrix(FALSE,5,5); im[cbind(x,y)] <- TRUE; image(im)`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I thought `igraph` might be the way to go here, I think you can do it more simply like:

```
result <- apply(df, 1, function(pt) 
  (pt["x"] == df$x &  abs(pt["y"] - df$y) == 1) |
  (abs(pt["x"] - df$x) == 1 &  pt["y"] == df$y)    
)
diag(result) <- 1
```

And avoid the loopiness and get the same result:

```
> identical(adjacency.coordinates(x,y),result)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: but your resulting matrix is not the same as the desired output from `adjacency.coordinates(x,y)`...

Comment: @Ben - I realise that - it does replicate the op's `image` call though, and does generate an `adjacency matrix` as per the wikipedia definition. To be honest i'm confused as to the what the result from the `adjacency.coordinates(x,y)` function represents.

Comment: Hi all, Thanks a bunch for the response. My adjacency.coordinates is based on the fact that when comparing two sets of coordinates, the sets are adjacent if either the difference between the x values is 0 and the y values is 1 or vice versa. That might not be the best explanation. All I really want to do is find out how to get an adjacency matrix out of a list of coordinates. Just hitting a wall... Thanks again, everyone.

Comment: Awesome. It totally works. Combining that with igraph's graph.adjacency() and clusters() let me separate all the clusters in an image and analyze them separately.

Comment: This solution is checking 4 neighbors for each vertex in the grid. Any idea on how a 8-neighbors solution would look like?

Comment: FWIW, the condition to check for a 8-neighborhood would be `(abs(pt["x"] - df$x) <= 1 & abs(pt["y"] - df$y) <= 1)`