# R programming - from a matrix containing points to neighbours list

Tags: r

I know there is a R method that enables programmers to convert neighbours list to a matrix.
I am trying to do the opposite process; is there anyway that I can convert a matrix that contains x and y coordinates of points to a neighbours list?

thank you

PS: I tried the following:

```
require(spdep)
mat2listw(myMatrix)$neighbours
```

but this is causing a problem since myMatrix has to be a square matrix...in my case my matrix is 11*2, which is not square.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: Something like `which(x,arr.ind=TRUE)` if you're using an adjacency matrix. I suppose you know about the `igraph` package...

Comment: This question may be of assistance: [how to create adjacency matrix from grid coordinates in r?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075232/how-to-create-adjacency-matrix-from-grid-coordinates-in-r/16076082) - it sounds similar but I can't tell for sure without seeing your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following.

```
# need indices.  Use Names or numeric index
rr <- if(is.null(rownames(myMatrix))) seq(nrow(myMatrix)) else rownames(myMatrix)
cc <- if(is.null(colnames(myMatrix))) seq(ncol(myMatrix)) else colnames(myMatrix)

inds <- as.matrix( expand.grid(X=rr, Y=cc) )


## as a data.frame
data.frame(inds, Dist=myMatrix[inds])

## as a list
ret <- apply(inds, 1, function(i) list(c(i, Dist=myMatrix[rbind(i)])))
# possibly unlist if needed
unlist(ret, recursive=FALSE)
```

#### Sample Data

```
set.seed(1)
myMatrix <- matrix(sample(8, 22, TRUE), ncol=2, dimnames=list(LETTERS[1:11], letters[1:2]))
myMatrix
```

Comment: What is `nms`? This answer errors out for me because it hasn't been created.

Comment: @thelatemail Whoops! `nms` was supposed to be `inds`. I have corrected in the last edit.  Thanks for the catch